# how to display values on top of each column in column chart.How to accomplish this

Tags: plot, highcharts, series

I want to display values on top of each column in column chart.How to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable datalabales (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.dataLabels.enabled)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uubCY/

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
```